# Java class in JavaFX-project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build, javafx

I recently started learning JavaFX.

At the moment I can't build any JavaFX project with Java class in Eclipse.
For every input I get error "package does not exist"
Path to JRE is set in project's properties.

Same class compiles if it is Java-project (not JavaFx).

What should I check in project settings or Eclipse prefferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you download the plug-in? You might want to try Exadel's plug-in http://exadel.org/javafxplugin - you should be able to compile your script fine. FYI: I work for Exadel.